# Removing footer on last pages of a chapter

Tags: header-footer, koma-script

Using `scrpage2` with `scrbook`, how can I make it so that there is no footer on the last pages of a chapter (so that the white is not interrupted)?

Comment: With "last pages", do you mean blank even pages before new chapter-starting odd pages?

Comment: @lockstep: the guidelines for French typography specify that page numbers in footer have to be removed at the end of partial pages finishing chapters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest

```
 \usepackage{etoolbox}
 \preto\chapter{\thispagestyle{endchapterstyle}}
```

where `endchapterstyle` is a page style defined as the normal one, but with empty footer.

The command `\chapter` has the responsibility to clear the page. But a direct command `\thispagestyle{endchapterstyle}` might be preferable. Or

```
\newcommand{\closechapter}{\thispagestyle{endchapterstyle}}
```

so that you can change your mind later and leave in place `\closechapter` after having redefined it.

Comment: Right. I'm actually using an `\input` for each chapter, so I could probably call `\thispagestyle{endchapterstyle}` after each call to `\input`. That said, I've already defined `scrplain` and `scrheadings`. How can I add more styles?

Comment: @Raphink: from page 141 in the KoMaScript manual.

Comment: @Raphink: the ``\\`` is ignored as the footer is typeset in horizontal mode; use `\parbox[t]{6mm}{\hrule\vspace{2pt}\centering\pagemark}`

Comment: thanks. As you can see, I actually decided to go with `\defstyle` instead, and it works really well :-)

Comment: Note: I've had cases of short last pages where the style was applied to the last-but-one page instead of the last one. To prevent this, I now use: `\mbox{}\hfill\thispagestyle{endchapterstyle}` to make sure the style is applied to the last page.

Answer (score 1):

For the record, here is my implementation of @egreg's answer:

```
\cfoot[\rule{6mm}{0.8pt}\\\pagemark]{\rule{6mm}{0.8pt}\\\pagemark}              
\ofoot[]{}                                                                      
\lehead[]{}                                                                     
\cehead[\headerfont\textsc{\titlehead}]{}                                     
\cohead[\headerfont\textsc{\chaphead}]{}                                      
\ohead[]{}                                                                      

\defpagestyle{chapterend}%                                                      
  {%                                                                            
    {\hfill\headerfont\textsc{\titlehead}\hfill}                                
    {\hfill\headerfont\textsc{\chaphead}\hfill}                                 
    {}                                                                          
  }%                                                                            
  {{}{}{}} % Nothing in footer                                                  

\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{scrheadings}                                  

\newcommand{\closechapter}{\thispagestyle{chapterend}}
```