# French typography recommendations

Tags: typography, french

> **This question led to a new package:**
>   [`impnattypo`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/impnattypo)

The French government publications office (Imprimerie Nationale) publishes a list of recommendations for French typography. I'm wondering how to implement some of these in LaTeX. I might actually come up with more later as I continue reading this booklet.

**End of chapters/parts**

In addition to [the recommendations of removing footers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20488/removing-footer-on-last-pages-of-a-chapter) on the last page of chapters/parts, it is recommended that these pages do not have less than 6 lines. I am guessing (it is not written) that if there are less than 6 lines, it is recommended to increase that number by forcing a page break in (one of) the previous page.

**Hyphenation rules**

- No odd page should finish with an hyphenated word;
- No more than 3 lines with hyphenated words should follow one another.

Comment: http://www.bvh.univ-tours.fr/Consult/consult.asp?numtable=B372615206%5F18229&numfiche=571&mode=1&ecran=0&offset=22&index=19 for a "solution" for hyphenation rule #1

Comment: You might be interested into this website about french typography : http://www.orthotypographie.fr/.
I think it is often less dogmatic than the I.N. and supported by more detailed arguments.

Comment: Thank you @AlfredM. I know about this website and use it from time to time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> No odd page should finish with an
>   hyphenated word;

`\brokenpenalty=10000` will forbid any page (neither recto nor verso) from ending with a hyphen.

> No more than 3 lines
>   with hyphenated words should follow
>   one another.

`\doublehyphendemerits=1000000000` will strongly discourage two hyphenations in a row.

Answer (score 9):

I'll give my non answer too.

It's in principle possible to have at least six lines in the final page of a chapter provided that the last paragraph is at least six lines long. Define

```
\newcommand{\closechapter}{%
  \begingroup\widowpenalties 6 10000 10000 10000 10000 10000 0 
  \par\endgroup
  % other customizations for the final page
}
```

and write `\closechapter` immediately after the final chapter's period (requires e-TeX extensions that should be present in any recent TeX distribution). If the last paragraph is less than five lines long, one can write `\unskip\newline\indent\ignorespaces` instead of the blank line between the final two paragraphs.

However, as already pointed out, such an "automatic" check will probably destroy the spacing in the preceding page, with a high risk of an `Underfull \vbox`.

No automatic procedure can replace human eye and judgment. Ensuring at least six lines in the last page of a chapter needs human intervention that no machine can possibly do, because machines don't understand English, French, Italian, or the language the document is written in.

The possibilities are so many: what if the chapter ends with two lines after an enumerated list? What if there's a quotation or a displayed formula? How do we count lines?

I don't believe in strict rules such as those by the *Imprimerie Nationale*; while I do agree that a final chapter page two lines long should be avoided, I could be satisfied with five. And I could accept a final hyphen in an odd page if all alternatives are worse (there usually *are* better alternatives, though).

Comment: I can only select one answer... but this does work fine actually :-)

Answer (score 4):

Maybe not really answer your questions.

> it is recommended that these pages do not have less than 6 lines.

I think this is much similar to the issues of widows and/or orphans. As far as I can tell there is no *reliable* and *general* way to do this in TeX. The better way is still to rely on a good editor (I mean a human editor, not a text editor or whatever).

I don't suggest to force a page break in a previous page. That will definitely make the documents look worse. Underfull vbox is very easy to be spotted by eyes and should be avoided as much as possible. It does much more harm than a few points of underfull or overfull hbox.

> Hyphenation rules.

This can be partially addressed by microtypography, namely protrusion, expansion, and sometimes tracking.

When using pdftex, launch the `microtype` package. Its document is quite comprehensive and also contains a brief but good introduction to microtypography.

When using luatex, though `microtype` has support for it since luatex 0.4, support for opentype fonts loaded with `luaotfload`/`fontspec` is still in a upcoming version the last time I check. But you can use

```
\pdfprotrudechars2
\pdfadjustspacing2
```

to turn on these features. And with the `protrusion` and `expansion` features to setup the factors. With `fontspec`, use `RawFeature = {protrusion = ...}`, or define a new font feature or other methods. See documents of `luaotfload` for these two features. See `fontspec` documents for setting features.

With microtypography, the hyphenation is largely improved, and you will see much less hyphenation. Therefore much less chance you get three successive lines with hyphenations or a last in odd page with hyphenated work.

However this just reduces the chance of such things happening (dramatically), not prevent anyway. But if there are still such hyphenations left, they should be very few and can be addressed by an editor.

Comment: `microtype` is really nice indeed, but I switched to XeTeX because my document uses quite a few different fonts, and XeTeX is not supported by `microtype`. How can I do something equivalent with XeTeX?

Comment: @Raphink, switch to LuTeX. It's the future and it can do much all the things XeTeX can do plus those it cannot do.

Comment: @Yan Zhou: Is LuaTex compatible with LaTeX packages (such as `bibleref`)? When it comes to the future, I've tried ConTeXt which was very nice but wouldn't play nicely with such specific packages...

Comment: @Raphink: The [beta version](http://xetex.tk/mediawiki/index.php/Microtype_package_%28preliminary_version%29) supports it. I have used it successfully.

Comment: @Raphink Does ConTeXt support latex packages as `bibleref`? I think it does not support any latex package since it is totally another format at all. Personally I don't think it is the future. ConTeXt has been around almost as long as LaTeX2e. LuaTeX should act as a drop in replacement for pdfTeX. The most user noticeable change is fonts and encodings. However I guess you use fontspec any way and you will find the switch much smoother than the switch from pdfTeX to XeTeX. For specific packages you can only find out by using it.

Comment: @Emre: right, but then I need a newer version of XeTeX, too.

Comment: @Yan Zhou Of course ConTeXt does not support any LaTeX packages, but usually provides the same functionality (and maybe more, I don't know). If you miss anything in ConTeXt you should simply ask. Chances are it can be implemented with what is already there.

Comment: @helcim Of course I know that. I simply repeated his question and answered it so.

Comment: @Yan Zhou Sorry for misunderstanding. It's clear to me now.